# PHP Mysql query updating multiple table even if some table are empty

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
      $update = ("UPDATE branch, custodian, atm_machine_list, computer_list 
        SET branch.branch_name = '$branch_name', 
            custodian.branch_name = '$branch_name', 
            atm_machine_list.branch_name = '$branch_name',
            computer_list.branch_name = '$branch_name',
            branch.branch_code = '$branch_code',
            branch.branch_address = '$branch_address',
            branch.manager = '$manager',
            branch.contact = '$contact' 
        WHERE branch.branch_name LIKE '%$edit_id%'
        AND custodian.branch_name LIKE '%$edit_id%'
        AND atm_machine_list.branch_name LIKE  '%$edit_id%'
        AND computer_list.branch_name LIKE '%$edit_id%'");
```

I am trying to update multiple tables (branch, custodian, atm_machine_list, computer_list)
I want my query to still update even if some of the table are empty.

for example there is a branch_name from custodian and no branch name on atm_machine_list then it will still update disregarding atm_machine_list but updating custodian at the same time.

Hope someone will help me.
Thanks

Comment: show your query please and also related php code

Comment: the query is in branch_list hyperlink

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: @NicoGestiada: do not post image. paste your query in your question

Comment: okay, sorry newbie

Comment: there is no INNER JOIN in your query.

Comment: @david it is an implicit join -> inner join

Comment: have a look at [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/) link to convert your query to explicit join. So you can control what type of join you want to have

Comment: in your query, you simply include the tables. No `INNER JOIN` in any part of your query.

Comment: @david what OP is doing is an INNER JOIN since he is doing an implicit join. Just a different syntax for the same goal. Implicit joins are long deprecated but still valid on a functional standpoint